# Use Rx framework for a Winforms application with a lot of filter controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, system.reactive

I have a Winforms app (.net 3.5) with a DataGridView which shows data from a slow/complex query. And it also have a lot (~15 controls) of comboboxes, textboxes, checkboxes which are used to filter the grid view.

Right now it plain Winform event handler for these filter controls (methods such as xxxx_DropDownClosed, xxxx_TextChanged, etc are used to handle the user inputs, BackGroundWorker is used to refresh the data grid view asynced).

How to implement it in Rx framework? Will using Rx a better approach to handle this scenario?

Form code behind: (View)

```
public event EventHandler<Filter1EventArgs> Filter1Changed;
public event EventHandler<Filter2EventArgs> Filter2Changed;
public event EventHandler<Filter3EventArgs> Filter3Changed;
.....
private void Filter1_SelectIndexchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var h = Filter1Changed;
    if (h != null)
    {
        var value = .....
        h(sender, new Fitler1EventArgs(value));
    }
}
.......
// Repeat for all filters
```

Presenter.cs

```
_view.Filter1Changed += OnFilter1Changed;
_view.Filter2Changed += OnFilter2Changed;
_view.Filter3Changed += OnFilter3Changed;
......

private void OnFilter1Changed(boject sender, Filter1EventArgs e)
{
    _filter.Filter1 = e.Value;
    RefreshView();
    UpdateDropdownlistItems("Filter1"); // exclude filter1
}
...... 
// Repeat for all filters
```

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?  This is a very subjective question.  Is there something particularly dissatisfying about your current solution?

Comment: I'm wonder if it can help when users keep adding multiple filters  quickly - so the new filter can cancel the unfinished previous filtering at least. Not sure if it will bring other benefits.

Comment: post a code example showing how you are doing it now.

Comment: The code example has been posted.

Comment: Since I do not see anything in your code that looks like it may be processing new filters asynchronously, or any mechanism to cancel the previous request when they change another filter, I don't see anyway Rx can fundamentally improve your code.  You could rewrite with Rx but IMO it would just be a different way of coding the same solution.  Rx really shines when you need to setup asynchronous processing streams.  While your filter events are asynchronous, you aren't really doing any complex processing of the results.

Comment: Now for example, if `RefreshView` were split into 2 methods with these signatures: `Task<Data> GetDataAsync(Filter filter, CancellationToken token)` and `void RefreshView(Data data)` then Rx could indeed help you.

Comment: `Refresh()` uses `BackgroundWorker` to update the main data grid view asynchronously. What I want to do is treating all the filtering events as stream and using Rx to better organize the structure, and doing cancelling when users quickly set multiple filters, etc.